# Nuxt run dev fatal error with status code 500

Tags: node.js, npm, nuxt.js

I was working on a Nuxt.js project and everything was working perfectly, then suddenly the `npm run dev` failed. I tried to run it again and I am constantly getting this error:

```
 FATAL  Request failed with status code 500                                                                                          17:43:55

  at createError (node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js:16:15)
  at settle (node_modules/axios/lib/core/settle.js:18:12)
  at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd (node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js:201:11)
  at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:194:15)
  at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:441:20)
  at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1125:12)
  at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)


   ╭────────────────────────────────────────────────╮
   │                                                │
   │   ✖ Nuxt Fatal Error                           │
   │                                                │
   │   Error: Request failed with status code 500   │
   │                                                │
   ╰────────────────────────────────────────────────╯

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
```

I tried some typical solutions like removing the `node_modules` and `.nuxt` directories and installing the dependencies again, and went even further and re-installed `nodejs` but non of them worked. It is really strange since it happened suddenly while I wasn't actually changing anything on the code, however I even recovered the latest working version of the app just to be sure, but that didn't help either. Whatever is it, is not related to the project codes since the same code was working before without any error.

Comment: What version of nuxt are you using? try locking it at 2.4.5

Comment: @arielnmz 2.4.2

Comment: Hi, I opened more than 3 tabs on my nuxt app and the pages load continuously. This same error appeared on the terminal. Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 4):

I found the solution myself and I share it so no one else has to spend half a day figuring what is wrong.

**Solution**

A failed `axios` request inside the `nuxt.config.js` has caused this problem. So find the reason why the `axios` request throws the error, which is most probably because of a change in the api you are trying to call.

Comment: Hi, how did you fix this error? I guess, this is not yet the solution: `probably because of a change in the api you are trying to call`